# Getting countries to display on the geotool map

Tags: java, geotools

I am using geotools map and finding it hard to work out how to display the counties on the map using java?

new to java so please explain in as much detail as possible, thanks.

Comment: You need to show some code and what you have tried thus far. We need to know which part you are stuck at.

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing?